# Regular Expression between two words

Tags: javascript, ajax, regex, parsing

I will really appreciate your help. What happens is that my code gets a string vía ajax from a php file. The php file returns a long string that contains the following `"css":["DSK\/y"],"js":["V5Llk","1dVnw"],"onload":["goURI(\"\\\/procedure\\\/376993639056176\\\/?context=create\");"],"bootloadable":{"IframeShim":{"resources":[...`.

What I want is to get the number `376993639056176` with javascript that is a server variable and keep a process with it. Can you help me please?

Comment: And is that number *always* 15 digits long? Is it always preceded by `/` and followed by `\\\`? What parts of that string will be consistent? The key part of 'regular expressions' is that they can be used to match content from within a regularly-formatted string; if the string *isn't* regular (or isn't predictably-formatted ) then then regex starts to fail. And what do you mean by '...and keep a process with it'? Assign it to a variable, call a function, initiate an, or another, Ajax request..?

Comment: What is the `...` on your question? Please post the entire result

Comment: @DavidThomas nope, its a numeric string but it comes always after the "procedure" word with the \\\/.  Thanks

Comment: @BrunoVieira I can't post this complete, it's a string near 2000 char long. But this I complemented it.

Comment: See the edit in my answer and the functional fiddle

Comment: Is that an actual JSON string (check with [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/))? If it *is* then there's better tools than regular expressions for retrieving portions of the string (in this case regex might still be needed, but JSON-decoding/parsing first will, at least, limit the scope for mistakes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server is returning a JSON with several information and you want the number part of the "onload" property of it. You can do the following

The following function will get only the digits from your String

```
var serverJSONString = stringReturnedByServer();
var longUri = serverJSONString.onload[0]; //This will get only the "onload" string;
var decodedNumber = longUri.replace (/[^\d]/g, "");
alert(decodedNumber);
```

Here's a functional [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brunovieira/MqUsm/)

Comment: Okay, I was not very clear. I just edited the question, can you check it please? Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

If the only numbers in that string are actually the ones you're looking for you can use a regex like

```
 var regex = new RegExp("[^0-9]*([0-9][0-9]*)[^0-9]*","g")
 var number = yourString.replace(regex,"$1");
```

Comment: But its not the only numeric string.

Comment: So what's the fixed pattern? the onload":["goURI(\"\\\/procedure\\\/WHATEVER_IS_HERE\\\/?.... ?or even the goURI string can be different?